# CIM CreateCustomerPaymentProfile Error

Tags: python, authorize.net

I am trying to create multiple payment profiles for my customers auth net profile using the this method.

```
def createAuthnetPaymentProfile(profileID, tries = 3):
    profile = client.factory.create("CreateCustomerPaymentProfile")
    profile.merchantAuthentication = merchantAuthentication
    profile.customerProfileId = profileID
    profile.paymentProfile = getAuthnetProfile(profileID, tries).paymentProfiles  
    payment_simple_type = client.factory.create('PaymentType')
    card_simple_type = client.factory.create('CreditCardSimpleType')
    payment_simple_type.creditCard = card_simple_type
    profile.payment = payment_simple_type
    profile.payment.creditCard = card_simple_type   
    profile.validationMode.value = "none"
    profileResult = makeAuthnetCall(client.service.CreateCustomerPaymentProfile, profile, tries)
    checkForError(profileResult)
    return profileResult.customerPaymentProfileId
```

However this returns this error **AuthnetError: E00029: Payment information is required.**

What might be the problem with my code.

Comment: What merchant account are you using - they may have more info on the error code

Comment: Authorize.net ..the error code is documented E00029 Payment information is required.(Payment information is required when creating a subscription or payment profile.) Which i have already included in my code.